# Роутинг в ASP.NET Core для API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, маршрутизация

помогите с роутингом в ASP.NET Core, мне нужно добиться такого формата обращение к API: https://api.site.com,
Такой формат не предлогать: https://www.site.com/api т.к. это легко сделать) А меня интересует именно первый вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно писать собственный роутер. Вот пара вспомогательных ссылок:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287716/asp-net-core-mapping-subdomains-to-areas
2. https://crookm.com/journal/2018/routing-by-subdomain-in-asp-net-core-mvc/